# MongoDB reduce functions is not running

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've translated the follow sql statment to map reduce:

```
select
    p_brand,    p_type,     p_size, 
    count(ps_suppkey) as supplier_cnt
from 
    partsupp, part
where 
    p_partkey = ps_partkey
    and p_brand <> 'Brand#45'
    and p_type not like 'MEDIUM POLISHED %'
    and p_size in (49, 14, 23, 45, 19, 3, 36, 9)
    and ps_suppkey not in (
            select 
            s_suppkey
            from 
            supplier
            where 
            s_comment like '%Customer%Complaints%'
        )
group by 
    p_brand, p_type, p_size
order by 
    supplier_cnt desc, p_brand, p_type, p_size;
```

Map reduce function:

```
db.runCommand({
    mapreduce: "partsupp",
    query: {
        "ps_partkey.p_size": { $in: [49, 14, 23, 45, 19, 3, 36, 9] },
        "ps_partkey.p_brand": { $ne: "Brand#45" }
    },
    map: function() {
        var pattern1 = /^MEDIUM POLISHED .*/;
        var pattern2 = /.*Customer.*Complaints.*/;

        var suppkey = this.ps_suppkey.s_suppkey;

        if( this.ps_suppkey.s_comment.match(pattern1) == null ){
            if(this.ps_suppkey.s_comment.match(pattern2) != null){
                emit({p_brand: this.ps_partkey.p_brand, p_type: this.ps_partkey.p_type, p_size: this.ps_partkey.p_size}, suppkey);
            }
        }
    },
    reduce: function(key, values) {
        return values.length;
    },
    out: 'query016'
});
```

The output result (seems to me) has no one reduce:

```
{
        "result" : "query016",
        "timeMillis" : 46862,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 122272,
                "emit" : 54,
                "reduce" : 0,
                "output" : 54
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: your reduce function is incorrect and possibly your map function as well - you must return from reduce the same format as the second argument to your emit call.  So in emit you want to have second argument as a NUMBER (like 1) and in reduce you need to iterate over values and add them up.  Also, you should use aggregation framework and not map-reduce for this unless your result set is expected to be huge.

Comment: Actually this.ps_suppkey.s_suppkey is a MongoDB NumberLong i was thinking if this is the problem. What do you think Asya?

Comment: the key (first argument to emit) can be anything, basic type, document, whatever.  Second argument can be anything also but whatever its type it must be the same as what reduce function is emitting.  Have you considered that each combination of your key only occurs once?

Comment: yes i thouth that. i've tried only one line in reduce function: return 0; In this case all the documents will be zero as value. But it doesn occurs. the values are equals suppkey, the second parameter from the emit function.

Comment: Or having no one key to reduce, doesnt get in inside reduce function?

Comment: reduce means combine multiple emitted values for a particular key into one value.  If you only have one value for every unique key then what would reduce function be reducing?

Answer (score 1):

The map function outputs key and value pairs.

The reduce function's purpose is to combine multiple values for the same key.  This means that if particular key value is only emitted once it has only one value and there is nothing to reduce.

This is one of the reasons that you must output the value in your emit statement in exact same format that reduce function will be returning.

Map outputs:

```
emit(key1, valueX);
emit(key1, valueY);
emit(key2, valueZ);
```

Reduce combines valueX and valueY to return new valueXY for key1 and the final result will be:

```
key1, valueXY
key, valueZ
```

Notice that reduce was never called on key2.  Reduce function may be called zero, once or multiple times for each key value, so you have to be careful to construct both the map and reduce functions to allow for that possibility.

Your map function doesn't emit a correct value - you want to be counting so you have to output a *count*.  Your reduce function must loop over the already accumulated counts and add them up and return the combined count.  You may want to look at some examples provided in the MongoDB documentation.

You can probably do this much simpler using the Aggregation Framework - I don't see the need for MapReduce here unless you are expecting to output a huge amount of results.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you called `emit(value,key)` instead of `emit(key,value)`.

As others have already stated, the mapped value and the reduced value must have the same structure. If you just want to make a count, map a value=1 and in the reduce function just return `Array.sum(values)`.